# What is the origin of the ring current in the Earth's magnetosphere?

Tags: magnetic-fields, astrophysics, geophysics, geomagnetism

Is ring current caused by gradient-curvature drift? I can't find a website that explicitly says that, they just call it 'longitudinal drift' and don't specify the mechanism, which I assume is particles drifting from one field line to the next - i.e. grad B drift and curvature drift?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The ring current is caused by Gradient-Curvature drift of *high-energy* ions. In contrast, the plasmasphere is defined by the presence of *low-energy* ions.